# tableview not working - [UIViewController tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uitableview, xib

I'm trying to init a `uitableview` using `xib` but when I run the app in simulator, the below exception is thrown.

```
2013-06-16 10:40:48.552 CoreDataExample[60661:c07] -[UIViewController tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x81765a0
2013-06-16 10:40:48.554 CoreDataExample[60661:c07] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIViewController tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x81765a0'
```

Below the steps that i have followed trying to start the tableview:

1. Add *`UITableViewDelegate`* and *`UITableViewDataSource`* in my `viewController`.
2. Insert the *`tableview`* into a view in my *`viewController.xib`*.
3. Create *`datasource`* and *`delegate`* in it files's owner (pressing control key and draging the mouse's arrow from component to file's owner and selecting the option delegate for example).
4. Implement the methods *`- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section`* and *`- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`* in my `viewController.m`.

Below the implemetation of two methods:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{

    return 10;

}



- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    UITableViewCell *cell = nil;

    static NSString *identifier = @"identifier";

    cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:identifier];

    if(cell == nil){
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:identifier];
    }

    cell.textLabel.text = @"Olá";
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = @"Subtitle" ;
    [cell setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryDetailDisclosureButton];


    return cell;
}
```

ViewController.h below:

```
@interface CDEMainViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource>

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section;

@end
```

Comment: Probably you have not set your view controller to be delegate and datasource.

Comment: Can you post your "myviewcontroller.h".  It seems like you're setting the tableview's delegate to an object that does not follow the UITableViewDelegate protocol.

Comment: Yes, issue in setting the delegate and datasource of the tableview.

Comment: @Putz1103, I have edited the post and put my viewController.h there.

Comment: In your viewcontroller's `viewDidLoad` method can you try to add the datasource and delegate for your tableview by calling `[tableview setDataSource:self]` and `[tableview setDelegate:self]`.  See if that makes it work?

Comment: @Putz1103, It didn't work.
I had already tried it, but seem no make sense because i do it when i drag mouse's arrow from component to file's owner in xib file.
am I wrong about it?

Comment: Check out IronMan's answer.  It's possible that you are not using your CDEMainViewController in your project at all.  The nib could just be loading a default implementation of a UIViewController.  Have you set a breakpoint in your viewcontroller class's `viewDidLoad` to see if it ever gets called?

Comment: I put a breakpoint in my *CDEMainViewController's" didLoad method, and It seem to be being crashed before, but I have no idea why.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

In XIB, Click on the File Owner, Check the Class Type. I guess it is UIViewController.
If it is `UIViewController` change it to `CDEMainViewController`. It will work properly.

Comment: it had already been done and checked too.
In a first seen, It seen to be it that you have described but when I created the *objective-c class* I checked the *With xib for user interface* option. So I believe that the files's owner would be my CDEMainViewController.

Comment: @AlessandroGarcez: It should, but the error message `-[UIViewController tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:]: unrecognized selector ...` indicates that the message is sent to an instance of UIViewController, and not CDEMainViewController as you expected.

Comment: Of course @MartinR, in my appDelegate I have initialized a instance ogf *UIViewController* while it should be a instance of *CDEMainViewController*.
thanks so much for the help

Answer (score 5):

In your ViewController XIB, Right click on the Tableview, Check the tableview datasource and delegate may be connected with view, not with File Owner, Disconnect  these and connect again tableview datasource and delegate with File Owner, This resolved my issue. Please check screen shots also for refrence.

**InCorrect Image**

[image]

**Correct Image**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Have you set method?:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView;
```

Comment: I have implemented it in the viewController.m

Answer (score 0):

Try open xib-file and reconnect IBOutlet of the tableView. Hope that helps you.